# css background-image: url(''); não acha a rota local da minha imagem

Tags: css3, background-image

1. Eu estou usando Ubuntu
2. Eu coloco (ctrl + v) a imagem que eu quero na tela de entrada (desktop)
3. Eu abro o terminal (ctrl + alt + t)
4. No terminal, faço: ls (a imagem não aparece)
5. Eu então faço: cd Desktop
6. Agora eu vejo o nome do arquivo da imagem, vamos supor que seja: woods.png
7. Eu faço: pwd
8. O retorno do meu terminal é: /home/meu-user/Desktop
9. Eu copio esse retorno e concateno com: /woods.png
10. Eu vou no css, e tento usar a imagem

Código

```
    
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            /*background-image: url('/static/images/woods.png');*/
            background-image: url('/home/meu-user/Desktop/woods.png');
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: bottom;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

11. No Django, a imagem abriu normalmente, usando o caminho especificado acima (comentado)
12. O mesmo não acontece quando tento a imagem localmente, mesmo usando o local exato dela
13. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: A imagem é .png mesmo? tentou tirar essa primeira `/` do caminha da imagem? Deixa só `home/meu-user/Desktop/woods.png`

Comment: Sim, está nas configurações dela, e sim, também já tentei retirar /, mas há algum erro de sintaxe cujo qual eu estou inapto para identificar :(

Comment: Primeiramente, você não pode colocar essa imagem no diretório de seu projeto? Já começa sendo má prática tentar acessar dados fora do projeto...

Comment: Eu já tenho a configuração do Django (está comentada no código). Eu queria saber duas formas de se fazer, dentre elas, puxando fora da pasta do projeto. Funciona no Windows, mas não consigo de form alguma no Ubuntu. Em resumo, é isso.

Comment: Qual o caminho de diretório do seu projeto (`pwd`)? Assim, posso melhorar minha resposta de modo a se encaixar melhor com o seu cenário.

Answer (score 4):

Ao utilizar `/home/meu-user/Desktop/woods.png`, ele está na verdade buscando na sub-pasta `/home/meu-user/Desktop/woods.png` do seu projeto.

Suponhamos que o diretório do seu projeto seja `/home/meu-user/projeto`, nesse caso ele estaria buscando a imagem em:

```
/home/meu-user/projeto/home/meu-user/Desktop/woods.png
```

O que é diferente de:

```
/home/meu-user/Desktop
```

Dessa forma, basta preencher da seguinte maneira:

`../Desktop/woods.png`

Arquitetura de diretório usado como exemplo:

```
raiz (/) ----- home ------ meu-user ------- projeto
                                   \
                                    \------ Desktop ----- woods.png
```

**Observação: Ao usar um *software* e seu diretório padrão do sistema `/var/www`, por motivos de segurança sua aplicação possui restrição de acesso a outros diretórios como `/home`.**

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua dica, faz bastante sentido. Eu tentei ../Desktop/woods.png assim como tentei /var/www/Desktop/woods.png e não surtiram efeito. Que coisa triste :(, mas muito obrigado.